# Django POST request data from Javascript fetch is displayed, but i get an error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to send data with Javascript fetch and I keep getting the error: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".

**inside index.js:**

```
fetch('save_user_post/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        credentials: 'same-origin',
                        headers:{
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': user_post_form_csrf.value,
                    },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            'input_user_post_value': input_user_post.value,
                    }) 
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        
                            return response.json()
                    })
                    .then(user_post_save_result => {

                        console.log(user_post_save_result )
                    
                    })
```

**and then in views.py:**

```
def save_user_post(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
            return JsonResponse({"error": "no POST method"}, status=400)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.body) #here I checked if I can receive this data
        data_of_post = json.loads(request.body)
        input_user_post_value = data_of_post.get('input_user_post_value', '')
        print(f'input_user_post_value is {input_user_post_value}') #here I checked if I can get exactly this value
        post_save_result = {'post_saved_or_not': 'saved'}
        return JsonResponse(post_save_result)
```

Although both print() commands display valid fetch data, the error relates to the line data_of_post = json.loads (request.body) is also shown. How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the last line as ‘ description_save_result’ isn’t defined in code

Comment: I changed it, but it's not a solution. As I wrote earlier: error page and console specifically point to the line data_of_post = json.loads (request.body) and the error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Comment: What is the value of request.body?